# Macbook AIR (2008, beginning). I installed KUBUNTU 20.04.2.0 - everything is fine, apart from the TOUCHPAD - Left button won't work. Please HELP

Tags: touchpad, macbook-air

This is my first Linux install, so please treat me as a beginner. I'm an experienced windows user though. I wanted to utilise my old MacBook air and it seems that Linux is really cool, even with 2Gb of RAM, however, during the installation the left mouse button didn't work, I managed to install it without one, however now I can boot in to Linux, but the left mouse button doesn't work either -((((( I'm not sure what to do, I tried

sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps

But that didn't help...

I'm 100% certain that the touchpad is working fine, as in the OS X - it's working 100% without any issues, any help would be appreciated.

Shall I try another LINUX would that help???

Thank you.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix by installing all the updates. The LUBUNTU had the same issue, but I wasn't even able to install it properly, the keyboard was not responsive... UBUNTU had no issues with the touchpad at all. Now I'm trying to figure out how to activate the keyboard backlight in KUBUNTU and how to free more RAM -)